# wordpress HTTP ERROR 500 when access to post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Wordpress in my localhost and after it works correctly I upload it to my server.

When I access to home page it works fine, but when I went to a post page (post detail or article page) I got HTTP ERROR 500 (This page isn’t working)

When I use default theme it works fine.

Comment: There's too much things that could cause an error 500. Check the server logs or temporary [enable error display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) on your code to get more information. If I had to guess, based on working home and crashing pages, I'd say: Go to Options > Permalinks and Save to rewrite the rules.

Comment: I have already try this 
ether when i'm trying to access via site.com/?p=1 
I got This page isn’t working
HTTP ERROR 500
the home page works fine

Comment: That was just a guess (not a good one it seems), so as I said, there's not enough information in your question to find whats causing the error. Please, check the logs, enable error display and update your question with more information.

Comment: Please can you help me how I can enable error display
I changed error_display:on  in php.ini but nothings

Comment: When I use default theme  It works fine

Comment: If it is working fine with default theme, then there could be issue with new theme. please check single.php, and other files in new theme folder. And error logs can be enabled, by placing "define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );" code in /wp-config.php file. Later, error logs will be generated in /wp-content/debug.log

Comment: YEs the problem come from single.php
When i remove all the code it works 
i can't understand why because in my loaclhost it works fine